# Font Face not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Why does the custom font for the voting up and down icons not appear in safari but fine in all other browsers!?
[At this website](http://huntingbanterlopes.com)

This is the snippet which seems to not be working.

```
@font-face {
            font-family: DeliciousRoman;
            src: url('http://huntingbanterlopes.com/css/entypo.eot');
            src: url('http://huntingbanterlopes.com/css/entypo.svg');
            src: url('http://huntingbanterlopes.com/css/entypo.svg');
            src: url('http://huntingbanterlopes.com/css/entypo.ttf');
            font-weight:400;
    }
```

Comment: 2 year old account? You should know better than to post questions like this.

Comment: Post your code in the question itself, not in a link offsite.

Answer (score 1):

The voting up and down buttons are appearing completely fine and as expected in Safari 6.1 (OS X Mountain Lion) and Safari (iOS7) on iPad.

I noticed in the code snippet you provided you have the .svg font listed twice. I's suggest removing one of them (should it be .woff instead?)